# ML data leaking subtlety

Tags: machine-learning, classification

On a 2 class classification problem (think spam detection, with some spam (positive), but a lot more non-spam (negative)), is it OK to share some negative samples between the validation and the training data set, but separate the positive samples, on the assumption that the negative population is on average the same between training and testing?

The negative population essentially provides a background against which to detect the positives, and so it doesn't matter if negative samples are leaked. Is that a good or a bad idea?

What this is hinting at is that, in some cases, it could be acceptable to leak differentially, depending on the class.

Comment: I wouldn't do it.  You can't simultaneously train a good classifier for the positive label and a bad classifier for the negative label - every misclassified input hurts the accuracy numbers for both symmetrically.  And the assumption that the training and testing populations are similar doesn't help much - the real risk is that you'll overfit the model to the training data and your validation set won't be able to tell you that there's a problem.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first inclination too, I would be wary of unexpected side-effects, but a colleague is pushing hard that it may be ok. In truth, I think the population changes over time for both negatives and positives, so that if you do allow some leaking of the negatives, you'll just end up limiting the shelf life/generalization of your model, as you say. Which could be ok if you plan on retraining before the population of negatives diverges too much, maybe.